# Converting Maven project to Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, project-structure

I'm quite new to gradle and I can't really find a solution to my problem. I have searched across the web to see anyone has done something similar following best practices.

I have several java projects being built with maven sharing a single project that contains all the environment profiles. So it looks like

```
Environment Project
---- pom.xml
---- config
-------- dev.properties
-------- stage.properties
-------- prod.properties
Project A
---- pom.xml
---- src
-------- main
------------ java
------------ resources
-------- test
------------ java
------------ resources
Project B
---- pom.xml
---- src
-------- main
------------ java
------------ resources
-------- test
------------ java
------------ resources
Project C
---- pom.xml
---- src
-------- main
------------ java
------------ resources
-------- test
------------ java
------------ resources
```

and so on.

Using profiles in maven I was able to build environment specific packages. At that time of doing the project structure I didn't really pay attention to see if this was best practice.

Anyways, what I want to know is if there is a similar approach to gradle to generate environment specific packages whilst sharing the config across multiple projects.

Comment: This [plugin](https://github.com/marceloemanoel/gradle-environments-plugin) aims to achieve what you want

Comment: problem with that approach is that its suitable if you want to copy project specific resource files. What if you want to do some filtering regardless of the project. In other words I have all the project variables in each of the properties in the environment project. so maven profile will take care of doing the filtering for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this plugin [gradle-properties-plugin](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-properties-plugin) which turned out to be exactly what i was after.

By default its simple enough to quickly implement environment based properties.